# Visual Studio 2019 set output directory for .tlog and .dll.recipe file

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have a project in Visual Studio and want all files generated during build under the `build\` subdirectory.

I set all output options I could find but there is still a `Debug\` folder created with the files: `projectname.dll.recipe` and subfolder `projectname.xxxx.tlog` which contains `.tlog` and `.lastbuildstate` files.

I know the `.tlog` files are from the *MSBuild File Tracker*, know idea what the `.dll.recipe` is.

How can I set the output directory for those files to `$(OutDir)`?

Comment: Did you have any concern about it?  Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue, if you have any concern or further issue, please feel free to let us know and we will  provide any better support for you.

Comment: Did you ever figure out where the projectname.dll.recipe file came from?  I'm building a ThumbnailProvider based on the windows sample and I changed all instances of "recipe" I found, but I still get the dll.recipe file.

Comment: No never could figure it out. But I also switched to CMake + CLion later so I stopped searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

**Function 1**

Open your project in VS IDE and then right-click on the project **Properties**-->**Configuration Properties**-->**General**--> change **Intermediate Directory** to `..\$(Configuration)`.

[image]

**Then**, rebuild your project to get what you want.

**Function 2**

**1)** add a file called `Directory.Build.props` in your solution folder like this:

[image]

**2)** add these content in the `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<Project>

<PropertyGroup>
<IntDir>..\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
</PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**3)** close VS Instance, delete any **Debug** folder in your solution folder.

Then restart VS(enable the function of the `Directory.Build.props`) to open your solution to build again and the files will be under the `$(OutDir)` path.

[image]